# Magento list of brand names on cms page

Tags: magento

This should be simple to achieve but since I'm a mage noob ((( I cant seem to get this to work.

I basically have category with all brands and what I'd like to do is to display brand names and links (without images) on the separate CMS page (brands).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the category you created has sub categories that are the brands, replace x with the id of your shop by brand category.

```
<?php    
    $brands = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(x)->getChildrenCategories();
?>

<?php foreach($brands as $brand): ?>
    <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $brand->getUrl() ?>">
             <?php echo htmlspecialchars($brand->getName()) ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
 <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply, sorry but, as I mentioned I'm a mage noob. Do I need to create phtml with above code? if so where should I place it and how can I reference it from CMS???

Comment: ooh I got it to work. I have created new phtml file called brands.phtml and placed it in template/catalog/product then inside of the CMS page used: {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="blanco.catalog.category.view" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/brands.phtml"}} thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Glad it worked.  If I helped answer your question please mark it as answered & up vote. Cheers.

Comment: I did try to rate, but unfortunately my reputation is less then 15 (((